# How to set Cscope->database-> Set init directory

Tags: emacs, dot-emacs

I am using xcode with emacs. But everytime I start emacs, I need to
go to menu 'CScope' -> Cscope->database -> set init Directory
and it pick the root directory of my source.

And then I click 'CScope' -> Cscope->database -> set init Directory->create list and index'

Is there anyway I can configure that in .emacs so that I don't need to do that every time i start emacs?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using [this cscope mode](http://www.mail-archive.com/gnu-emacs-sources@gnu.org/msg00205.html) it looks like you could do `M-x customize-variable RET cscope-last-directory RET`, set the variable to your favorite directory, and save the value. If not, you'll have to be more specific about how you are using cscope with Emacs.

Comment: I am mainly using cscope in emacs to search for definition of a function and they open the file contains that function in a new frame in emacs.

Comment: Where did you get the Cscope mode you are using with Emacs? If it came with Emacs, which version of Emacs do you have?

Answer (score 0):

refer to "Using Cscope on large projects(example: the Linux kernel)"

1. use **find** command build cscope.files

   find /path/to/project -name "*.h" -or -name "*.c" > /path/to/cscope/initdir
2. edit .emacs

   (setq cscope-initial-directory "/path/to/cscope/initdir")

PS: I use xcscope.el